# Handing focusing and unfocusing of multiple form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Here is a link to my [problem](http://jsfiddle.net/6c05jw95/)

```
$('#name').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Full Name*')
        $(this).val('');
        }).blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '')
        $(this).val('Full Name*');
});
    $('#email').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Email Address*')
        $(this).val('');
        }).blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '')
        $(this).val('Email Address*');
});
    $('#subject').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Subject*')
        $(this).val('');
        }).blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '')
        $(this).val('Subject*');
});
    $('#msg').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Your Message*')
        $(this).val('');
        }).blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '')
        $(this).val('Your Message*');
});
```

I've been trying to simplify this code, but because of my limited javascript knowledge I haven't been able to achieve this. I'm almost 100% sure that this could be written in much simpler - DRY form.

Comment: I'm looking at the higher-level problem here and I'm wondering if [`placeholder`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) is an acceptable solution, unless you have a need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to question something repetitive like that.

Here's a direct replacement for your idea.

```
function setValue(selector, text) {
    $(selector).focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == text)
            $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '')
            $(this).val(text);
    });
}

setValue('#name', 'Full Name*');
setValue('#email', 'Email Address*');
setValue('#subject', 'Subject*');
setValue('#msg', 'Your Message*');
```

Comment: Use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`

Comment: The repeated use of `$(this)` is also unnecessary. It's better to assign it to a variable once and reuse it: `var $this = $(this);`. The OP's code suffers from this as well. @tymeJV: +1 for suggesting the use of native browser properties for something so trivial. Don't be afraid to get your hands dirty with the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom date attribue, lets say `placeholder` on your inputs, and then give them a common class as well:

```
<input type="text" id="email" data-placeholder="Email Address" class="required" />
<input type="text" id="name" data-placeholder="Full Name" class="required" />
<input type="text" id="subject" data-placeholder="Subject" class="required" />
<input type="text" id="msg" data-placeholder="Your Message" class="required" />
```

And then use 1 event for all!

```
$(".required").focus(function() {
    var placeholder = $(this).data("placeholder");
    if (this.value == placeholder) this.value = "";
}).blur(function() {
    if (this.value == "") this.value = $(this).data("placeholder");
}).blur(); //trigger on load
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/odpu5gbn/

Comment: What about to remove the whole code and use `placeholder` instead?

Comment: @Regent -- Always an option - unless old browser support is an issue.

Comment: Believe it or not, there are a significant number of people who are still using a browser that doesn't support it, primarily older businesses where it is (or is perceived as) too expensive to be worth upgrading.

Comment: @KevinB -- Didn't believe it until my first corporate job... and then the nightmare never ended.

Comment: Suggestion: remove `required` class, and select the elements by `$('[data-placeholder]')`.

Comment: @EliasSoares -- Class selectors are faster than generic data selectors (not that performance is any kind of issue here) - plus these are a common group of elements and should have a common class.

Comment: Sure it will be faster, but i like clean HTML codes, no un-necessary classes. 

The performance will not be big deal here, unless his form has 500+ input fields. ;)

Comment: I would still use a common class, just maybe not `required` because `required` doesn't point to the functionality that is being attached to it.

Comment: Well, if there will be any other elements with `data-placeholder` in page, selecting `$('[data-placeholder]')` for event handlers will cause all kind of troubles. I suppose it's much more important than selection speed. While you can use special class for special group avoiding all problems. Just one more thing: it is not a bad idea to split "functionality" classes from "CSS" classes.

Comment: Well, `data-placeholder` should have the same behavior in entire page, so, i don't see any problems. 

A way to speed up, is use `$('input').on('focus', '[data-placeholder]', handler)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer for your problem, BUT:

If you are trying to put a placeholder to your input elements, why don't you just use HTML5 placeholder attribute?

[W3schools Attribute Placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

```
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
```

- This is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Comment: Why down-vote? It is a solution for the problem. Most simple than this?

Comment: Downvotes are not mine, but note MDN [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) (emphasis mine): *Do not use the `placeholder` attribute instead of a `<label>` element. Their purposes are different: the `<label>` attribute [sic] describes the role of the form element; that is, it indicates what kind of information is expected, the `placeholder` attribute is a hint about the format the content should take.* ***There are cases in which the `placeholder` attribute is never displayed to the user, so the form must be understandable without it.***

Comment: Sure Frédéric. In some small forms like login forms or newsletter form, or like this answer box in Stackoverflow, the placeholder works! 

BTW, the question author question is about a placeholder.

Comment: Indeed, I was just pointing out that implementing the placeholder through scripting would not be subject to the limitations mentioned on MDN, in addition to supporting more browsers. In practice, all the HTML5-compliant browsers I've used so far have indeed always displayed the placeholder, but you never know. Maybe the downvoters went through that train of thought.

Comment: @EliasSoares total score of -1 is not good, that's for sure, but at least there is +6 reputation. I still think that `placeholder` is not a bad idea (especially due to reducing code to zero). But these damned old browsers make life complicated even in SO...

Comment: While the `placeholder` attribute doesn't have the same visual affect in IE9, and there is no `placeholder` property on that DOM node, you can always call `element.getAttribute("placeholder")` to get that value cross-browser. +1 for this solution as it is forward-thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all your code revolves around 2 types of operation:

- check if the current value equals another value
- set a new value

Refactor that common logic into 2 separate functions:

```
function testIf(value) {
    return $(this).val() == value;
}
function setValue(value) {
    $(this).val(value);
}
```

You need to pass `this` as a context, which will allow you to keep your code inside the function as is:

```
testIf.call(this, 'Full Name*');
setValue.call(this, '');
```

Of course this approach focuses on your JavaScript code only. It all depends how much you want to impact your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

To throw my hat in the ring, this creates a basic patch for the `placeholder` attribute in non compatible browsers:

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d9qwxtmu/

```
$(document.documentElement).on("blur", function(event) {
    var target = event.target,
        placeholder = target.getAttribute("placeholder");

    if (/^\s*$/.test(placeholder) || "placeholder" in target) {
        // Either the placeholder doesn't exist or the browser already supports the
        // "placeholder" attribute, so bail out. Addmittedly, this is a weak test
        // for browser support, but should suffice as long as you don't explicitly
        // set the "placeholder" property on a text box.
        return;
    }

    if ("value" in target) {
        target.value = target.value === placeholder ? "" : target.value;
    }
});
```

This works with the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First name">
<input type="text">
```

If browsers natively support the `placeholder` attribute, we just bail out of this blur event handler. If the placeholder is an empty value, we also bail out. Only if the browser does not have a `placeholder` property on the event target and the placeholder value is not empty do we check the value of the INPUT tag.

Furthermore, since it uses jQuery's `on` method, event delegation is utilized so that only one snippet of JavaScript is needed for the whole page. The mere addition of `<input type="text" placeholder="foo">` will trigger this polyfill, even if the text box is created and appended at runtime.